How to create a sharp edge from this object?
im trying to figure our how to create sharp edges, I was following this tutorial of how to create the apple vision pro, and when the guy got to the part about creating share edge mine was none doing it like his.He mentioned extruding then scaling the edge to create the edge but mine was not performing in that manner is there something im missing to do that would make the edge sharpened so I can create the screen.


Bevel the edge to make it sharper?

Can you link to that tutorial? We haven't followed that tutorial, so have no idea what you're making or trying to make :)

In the panel on the right increase the "Mean Crease" value towards 1

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/UW6tYtchrWE, here's the video that I followed for reference
